# asp.net -SerialPort.DataReceived not add to listbox items

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, serial-port

I want add serial port data received to listbox

HTML

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
              <asp:ListBox ID="listbox1" runat="server" ></asp:ListBox>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

code behind

```
 Protected Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        data = SerialPort1.ReadExisting()
        listbox1.items.add(data) 'this not work
        msgbox(data) 'this work
 End Sub
```

Please help me

Comment: This isn't really on ASP.net is it?

Comment: yes, I edited the question

Comment: Are you trying to read the server's serial port, or the client (web browser)?

Comment: read the server serial port